# Sonarqube v.4.3.0 VSTS task “Publish Analysis Result” throw error “Could not fetch metrics” (404)

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

Since the update from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0, publishing the sonar qube results fail with this error for my react application:

```
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8644128Z ##[section]Starting: Publish Quality Gate Result
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8648466Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8648887Z Task         : Publish Quality Gate Result
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8649287Z Description  : Publish SonarQube's Quality Gate result on the VSTS/TFS build result, to be used after the actual analysis.
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8649650Z Version      : 4.3.0
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8649925Z Author       : sonarsource
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8650254Z Help         : [More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
2018-06-18T07:35:56.8650681Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-18T07:36:05.4520694Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
2018-06-18T07:36:05.4531287Z ##[error][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'
2018-06-18T07:36:05.4532808Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
2018-06-18T07:36:05.4534300Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
2018-06-18T07:36:05.5248790Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish Quality Gate Result
```

Found some similar errors on StackOverflow, but they seems to be more related to authentication.
Is it a bug in the VSTS task or is there a workaround?

**UPDATE: Some more detailed logs**

```
serverVersion=6.7.3.38370
dashboardUrl=https://XXXXXX/dashboard/index/XXXXXXcmp-ui-dev
ceTaskId=AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW
ceTaskUrl=https://XXXXXX/api/ce/task?id=AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW

2018-06-19T11:24:35.6562477Z ##[debug][SQ] Parse Task report file: projectKey=sonarqube-scanner
serverUrl=http://localhost:9000
serverVersion=6.5.0.27846
dashboardUrl=http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/sonarqube-scanner
ceTaskId=AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l
ceTaskUrl=http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l

2018-06-19T11:24:35.6564194Z ##[debug][SQ] Parse Task report file: projectKey=sonarqube-scanner
serverUrl=http://localhost:9000
dashboardUrl=http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/sonarqube-scanner
ceTaskId=AViCXLBOyOPDYliRRPPD
ceTaskUrl=http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AViCXLBOyOPDYliRRPPD

2018-06-19T11:24:35.6579126Z ##[debug][SQ] Parse Task report file: projectKey=dist
serverUrl=http://localhost:9000
serverVersion=6.5.0.27846
dashboardUrl=http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/dist
ceTaskId=AV2jO_7EtQnci7vN0TrW
ceTaskUrl=http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AV2jO_7EtQnci7vN0TrW

##[debug][SQ] Waiting for task 'AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW' to complete.
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/ce/task' with query "{"id":"AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW"}"
##[debug][SQ] Waiting for task 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l' to complete.
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/ce/task' with query "{"id":"AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l"}"
##[debug][SQ] Waiting for task 'AViCXLBOyOPDYliRRPPD' to complete.
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/ce/task' with query "{"id":"AViCXLBOyOPDYliRRPPD"}"
##[debug][SQ] Waiting for task 'AV2jO_7EtQnci7vN0TrW' to complete.
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/ce/task' with query "{"id":"AV2jO_7EtQnci7vN0TrW"}"
##[debug]Response: 404 Body: "{"errors":[{"msg":"No activity found for task 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'"}]}"
##[debug][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[debug][SQ] Publish task error: [SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AV6EiGo9XAfivOz6jp5l'
##[debug]Response: 200 Body: "{"task":{"id":"AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWPvWj0KNr8GlRD53mu0","componentKey":"XXXXXXcmp-ui-dev","componentName":"CMP Development UI","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AWQXyeRvZSHmKx_UWZLd","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:23+0000","submitterLogin":"XXXXXX","startedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:23+0000","executedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:29+0000","executionTimeMs":5631,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization"}}"
##[debug][SQ] Task status:SUCCESS
##[debug][SQ] Task complete: {"id":"AWQXyd5mNr8GlRD53mvW","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AWPvWj0KNr8GlRD53mu0","componentKey":"XXXXXXcmp-ui-dev","componentName":"CMP Development UI","componentQualifier":"TRK","analysisId":"AWQXyeRvZSHmKx_UWZLd","status":"SUCCESS","submittedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:23+0000","submitterLogin":"XXXXXX","startedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:23+0000","executedAt":"2018-06-19T11:24:29+0000","executionTimeMs":5631,"logs":false,"hasScannerContext":true,"organization":"default-organization"}
##[debug][SQ] Retrieve Analysis id 'AWQXyeRvZSHmKx_UWZLd.'
##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/qualitygates/project_status' with query "{"analysisId":"AWQXyeRvZSHmKx_UWZLd"}"
##[debug]Response: 200 Body: "{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":[{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"coverage","comparator":"LT","errorThreshold":"18","actualValue":"0.0"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_reliability_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"warningThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"new_security_rating","comparator":"GT","periodIndex":1,"actualValue":"1"},{"status":"OK","metricKey":"sqale_rating","comparator":"GT","warningThreshold":"1","actualValue":"1"},{"status":"ERROR","metricKey":"new_coverage","comparator":"LT","periodIndex":1,"errorThreshold":"25","actualValue":"0.0"}],"periods":[{"index":1,"mode":"previous_version","date":"2018-06-11T14:56:55+0000"}],"ignoredConditions":false}}"
##[debug][SQ] Generate analysis report.'
##[debug]Response: 404 Body: "{"errors":[{"msg":"No activity found for task 'AV2jO_7EtQnci7vN0TrW'"}]}"
##[debug][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[debug]Response: 404 Body: "{"errors":[{"msg":"No activity found for task 'AViCXLBOyOPDYliRRPPD'"}]}"
##[debug][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task' failed, status code was: 404
##[section]Finishing: Publish Quality Gate Result
```

**UPDATE: Definition**

[image: prepare]
[image: sources dir]

**UPDATE: Details of the analysis task**

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Run Code Analysis'
##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
##[debug]=> True
##[debug]Result: True
##[section]Starting: Run Code Analysis
==============================================================================
Task         : Run Code Analysis
Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
Version      : 4.3.0
Author       : sonarsource
Help         : This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.

[More Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
==============================================================================
##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_temp
##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
##[debug]loading SECRET_SONARQUBE_ENDPOINT
##[debug]loaded 4
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
##[debug]SONARQUBE_SCANNER_MODE=CLI
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0,sonar-scanner,bin,sonar-scanner = E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner
##[debug]which 'E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat'
##[debug]found: 'E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat'
##[debug]which 'E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat'
##[debug]found: 'E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat'
##[debug]system.debug=true
##[debug]E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat arg: -X
##[debug]exec tool: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   -X
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\sonar-scanner.bat -X"
INFO: Scanner configuration file: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\_tasks\SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055\4.3.0\sonar-scanner\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227
INFO: Java 1.8.0_171 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows Server 2016 10.0 amd64
DEBUG: keyStore is : 
DEBUG: keyStore type is : jks
DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
DEBUG: init keystore
DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
DEBUG: Create: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.sonar\cache
INFO: User cache: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.sonar\cache
DEBUG: Create: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.sonar\cache\_tmp
DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
DEBUG: Download: https://XXXXXX.com/batch/index
DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
DEBUG: Execution getVersion
INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.3
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
DEBUG: Work directory: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork
DEBUG: Execution execute
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/settings/values.protobuf | time=172ms
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=219ms
INFO: Server id: AWKRJbujkvyHj7QIqwwz
INFO: User cache: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/plugins/installed | time=15ms
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=62ms
DEBUG: Load plugins
DEBUG: Load plugins (done) | time=47ms
DEBUG: Plugins:
DEBUG:   * SonarPython 1.9.1.2080 (python)
DEBUG:   * Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication Plug-in for SonarQube 1.0 (authaad)
DEBUG:   * Svn 1.7.0.1017 (scmsvn)
DEBUG:   * SonarJS 4.1.0.6085 (javascript)
DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.0.1.4822 (csharp)
DEBUG:   * SonarJava 5.2.0.13398 (java)
DEBUG:   * SonarWeb 2.6.0.1053 (web)
DEBUG:   * Git 1.4.0.1037 (scmgit)
DEBUG:   * SonarFlex 2.4.0.1222 (flex)
DEBUG:   * SonarXML 1.5.0.1373 (xml)
DEBUG:   * SonarPHP 2.13.0.3107 (php)
DEBUG:   * SonarTS 1.6.0.2388 (typescript)
INFO: Process project properties
DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=15ms
INFO: Load project repositories
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/batch/project.protobuf?key=XXXXXX-dev | time=47ms
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=109ms
DEBUG: Available languages:
DEBUG:   * Python => "py"
DEBUG:   * JavaScript => "js"
DEBUG:   * C# => "cs"
DEBUG:   * Java => "java"
DEBUG:   * Web => "web"
DEBUG:   * Flex => "flex"
DEBUG:   * XML => "xml"
DEBUG:   * PHP => "php"
DEBUG:   * TypeScript => "ts"
INFO: Load quality profiles
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=XXXXXX-dev | time=93ms
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=93ms
INFO: Load active rules
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJphzkvyHj7QIqxLM&p=1&ps=500 | time=421ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJqUlkvyHj7QIqxSs&p=1&ps=500 | time=500ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRRrIwhnDVpZCHB5jb&p=1&ps=500 | time=40ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJq2xkvyHj7QIqxYS&p=1&ps=500 | time=32ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJqxokvyHj7QIqxXT&p=1&ps=500 | time=46ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJrTlkvyHj7QIqxd4&p=1&ps=500 | time=157ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJrdokvyHj7QIqxf3&p=1&ps=500 | time=130ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJsMgkvyHj7QIqxio&p=1&ps=500 | time=94ms
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt&activation=true&qprofile=AWKRJsfzkvyHj7QIqxjs&p=1&ps=500 | time=188ms
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1834ms
INFO: Load metrics repository
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/metrics/search?f=name,description,direction,qualitative,custom&ps=500&p=1 | time=16ms
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=79ms
INFO: Project key: XXXXXX-dev
DEBUG: Start recursive analysis of project modules
INFO: -------------  Scan CMP Development UI
INFO: Load server rules
DEBUG: GET 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=94ms
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=125ms
INFO: Base dir: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s
INFO: Working dir: E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Python were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.py : **/*.py
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js,**/*.jsx,**/*.vue
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Web were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.web : **/*.html,**/*.xhtml,**/*.rhtml,**/*.shtml
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Flex were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.flex : **/*.as
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language XML were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.xml : **/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.xsl
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PHP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.php : **/*.php,**/*.php3,**/*.php4,**/*.php5,**/*.phtml,**/*.inc
DEBUG: Declared extensions of language TypeScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.ts : **/*.ts,**/*.tsx
DEBUG: Initializers : 
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/node_modules/**
INFO:   **/*.test.tsx
INFO:   **/*.test.ts
INFO:   **/*.test.js
DEBUG: 'src\components\App\App.css' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\App\App.scss' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\App\App.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Footer\Footer.css' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Footer\Footer.scss' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Footer\Footer.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Header\Header.css' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Header\Header.scss' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\components\Header\Header.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\PendingIssues\Actions.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\PendingIssues\index.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\PendingIssues\Models.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\PendingIssues\PendingIssues.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\components\PendingIssues\Reducer.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\index.css' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\index.scss' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\index.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\logo.svg' indexed with language 'null'
DEBUG: 'src\registerServiceWorker.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\screens\Home.tsx' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\store\index.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\store\root-action.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\store\root-epic.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\store\root-reducer.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\store\store.ts' indexed with language 'ts'
DEBUG: 'src\styles\_theme.scss' indexed with language 'null'
INFO: 26 files indexed
INFO: 1 file ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PythonXUnitSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SonarJS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SonarJS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Properties' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Web' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'XML Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Analyzer for "php.ini" files' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
DEBUG: 'Generic Test Executions Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
DEBUG: 'Python Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PythonXUnitSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SonarJS' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SonarJS Coverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C#' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Properties' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: '[Deprecated] C# Integration Tests Coverage Report Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'C# Unit Test Results Import' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Web' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Flex' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Flex Cobertura' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'XML Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'PHP sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: 'Analyzer for "php.ini" files' skipped because there is no related file in current project
DEBUG: Sensors : SonarJavaXmlFileSensor -> SonarTS -> SonarTS Coverage -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor SonarTS [typescript]
DEBUG: TypeScript compiler is found in this directory E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\node_modules
DEBUG: It will be used for analysis of typescript files
DEBUG: Deploying bundle from `/sonarts-bundle.zip` to `E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork`
DEBUG: Checking node version
DEBUG: Using Node.js v8.11.1
DEBUG: Analyzing 16 typescript file(s) with the following configuration file E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\tsconfig.json
DEBUG: Setting 'NODE_PATH' to E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\node_modules
DEBUG: Starting external process `node --max-old-space-size=2048 E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork\sonarts-bundle\node_modules\tslint-sonarts\bin\tsrunner`
DEBUG: 'src/components/App/App.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/components/Footer/Footer.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
DEBUG: 'src/components/Header/Header.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'UTF-8'
DEBUG: 'src/components/PendingIssues/Actions.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/components/PendingIssues/Actions.ts' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/components/PendingIssues/Models.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/components/PendingIssues/Models.ts' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/components/PendingIssues/PendingIssues.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/components/PendingIssues/Reducer.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/components/PendingIssues/index.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/index.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/registerServiceWorker.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/screens/Home.tsx' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/screens/Home.tsx' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/store/index.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/store/index.ts' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/store/root-action.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/store/root-action.ts' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/store/root-epic.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: Not enough content in 'src/store/root-epic.ts' to have CPD blocks, it will not be part of the duplication detection
DEBUG: 'src/store/root-reducer.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
DEBUG: 'src/store/store.ts' generated metadata  with charset 'windows-1252'
INFO: Sensor SonarTS [typescript] (done) | time=16740ms
INFO: Sensor SonarTS Coverage [typescript]
INFO: Analysing [E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\coverage\lcov.info]
INFO: Sensor SonarTS Coverage [typescript] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=94ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
DEBUG: org.sonar.scanner.cpd.deprecated.DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for ts
DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language ts
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
INFO: 6 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 10 files
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/PendingIssues/PendingIssues.tsx
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/App/App.tsx
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/PendingIssues/Reducer.ts
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/Header/Header.tsx
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/Footer/Footer.tsx
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/store/root-reducer.ts
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/components/PendingIssues/index.ts
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/registerServiceWorker.ts
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/store/store.ts
DEBUG: Detection of duplications for E:/VSTSAgent-XXXXXX/_work/4/s/src/index.tsx
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 750ms, dir size=62 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 125ms, zip size=39 KB
INFO: Analysis report generated in E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork\scanner-report
DEBUG: Upload report
DEBUG: POST 200 https://XXXXXX.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=XXXXXX-dev&projectName=CMP%20Development%20UI | time=172ms
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 172ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://XXXXXX.com/dashboard/index/XXXXXX-dev
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at https://XXXXXX.com/api/ce/task?id=AWQ8KpFCNr8GlRD53mvk
DEBUG: Report metadata written to E:\VSTSAgent-XXXXXX\_work\4\s\.scannerwork\report-task.txt
DEBUG: Post-jobs : 
INFO: Task total time: 24.325 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 27.262s
INFO: Final Memory: 20M/261M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
##[debug]rc:0
##[debug]success:true
##[section]Finishing: Run Code Analysis
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer but have a similar issue with the new version of MSBuild. I have a .NetCore app & the build build fails in the prepare step. My error is: 2018-06-18T19:51:50.9479301Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}. I have a GitHub Issue opened but I'm stuck here.

Comment: What's the version of your sonarqube server? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT The version is 6.7.3 (build 38370). Unfortunately I don't have access to the VM yet, I'm going to request this access.

Comment: Can you share detail VSTS build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Can I share the link with a PM with you somewhere?

Comment: BTW: Publishing the results for my backend build works (MSBUILD). It only stopped to work for the frontend using the standalone scanner (without any changes to the code).

Comment: Look like your build is doing SQ analysis of multiple projects (XXXXXXcmp-ui-dev, sonarqube-scanner, dist). Do you confirm? Also it seems you are interacting with different SQ servers, of different version (6.7.3.38370 and 6.5.0.27846). One of the server is hosted on localhost. This look really suspicious to me. Can you check and give more details?

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam I'm only intendedly build project XXXXXXcmp-ui-dev. I don't know why there are other projects listed or what they are. I added screenshots of how I setup the analysis.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe sharing analysis logs (logs of the "perform analysis" task) will help.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam I added the output of the analysis task but removed time information because I reached the max  of 30k characters for this post...next logs will be a gist ;-)

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft hosted agent, or do you have your own private agent? It still don't understand why the publish task is finding multiple analysis results in the workspace. Maybe some leftovers from previous/concurrent runs?

Comment: Yes it's a private agent. I can't try a hosted pipeline because it will not have access to the sonarqube instance unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube extension make various http requests to the SonarQube server for various reasons. If your SonarQube server is using a custom/self-signed SSL certificate, it will fail for security reasons. You have to tell node.js that you trust this certificate using [NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file).

See details:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/VSTS-147

Comment: The certificate from godaddy-ca. I added some more detailed logs to my question.

Comment: Juline H, do you know the reason?

Comment: I am facing the same error with Sonar Qube 6.7.3 and a project that has more than 100 files to upload to sonarQube.  Any solution for the same? would upgrading to SonarQube 6.7.6 help much?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it SSL issues, i have faced the same issues when try to use http service connection.